# Pass variables to custom mail transport in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, gmail

Laravel provides the possibility to implement your own mail transport in order to send email over APIs that they aren't implemented in the framework itself by extending `Illuminate\Mail\Transport\Transport`. I have done so for the gmail API as this provides some benefits over sending over SMTP. There is however a scenario which is giving me some difficulties: the API requires you to impersonate a given user to send mail as that user. Currently, I'm using the 'from' address to perform that action.

```php
use Illuminate\Mail\Transport\Transport;
use Google\Client as GoogleClient;

class MailTransport extends Transport 
{
    public function send(Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage $message, &$failedRecipients = null) 
    {
        $client = new GoogleClient;
        // initialise the client further, code omitted
        $client->setSubject(
            array_key_exists(0, array_keys($message->getFrom()))
                ? array_keys($message->getFrom())[0]
                : self::DEFAULT_SUBJECT
        );
        // send the email here using the impersonated $client
    }
}
```

This works fine, however I'm running into an issue when I want to send a mail from a mail alias of that user. In that case, the from address doesn't match the google account to impersonate and sending the mail doesn't work. I'm looking for a way to pass the google account to impersonate to the Mailtransport. As an instance of this class is automatically created by the framework and only `Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage` can be used, my best solution right now is to add a custom header to the email which is read and then removed by the `MailTransport` class. This feels like a dirty workaround however, does anybody know a cleaner solution?